# What function does the chip on the HP Laserjet 1320 toner cartridge have?

Tags: laser-printer, hp-laserjet, toner

On the HP Laserjet 1200 cartridge and on many other toner cartridges for laser printers there's a small chip with two contact plates for contact with the printer. The chip doesn't seem to be connected to something inside the cartridge.

**What function does this chip have and does it ever need to be replaced? Can the cartridge function without this chip?**

Comment: Can you add an image? They could be ground plates, to ground the cartridge body to the chassis, which will ensure atmospheric static electricity doesn't pull toner out, affecting image quality. They could also be there to complete a circuit with the printer chassis, so the printer knows the lid is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The chip controls the printerhead and determines if a printer can still print. The chip can tell the printer that it cannot print anymore and has the ability to read how much ink or toner there is still left in the cardridge. It is connected with a flexible ribboncable.

When the cardridge runs out, it is meant to be tossed away as it is part of the cardridge.